# ocultar botones según rol package spatie laravel

Tags: laravel, permisos, users-roles

estoy tratando de ocultar botones según el rol del usuario, en este caso los botones se encuentran en el controller y yo ocultaba los botones que se encontraba en el blade de esta forma

> @can('permisoexample.permisoexample')
>   <...CODIGO...>
>   @endcan

pero en mi controller no lo puedo realizar así, adjunto código de mi controller y un ejemplo de como oculto el botón en mi blade.
El paquete que ocupo es [spatie](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission)

**BLADEexample.BLADE.PHP**

```html
@can('alumno.index')
<li class="nav-item">
  <a href="alumno" class="nav-link {{ (request()->is('alumno')) ? 'active' : '' }}">
    <i class="nav-icon fas ion-ios-person"></i>
    <p>Alumnos</p>
  </a>
</li>
@endcan
```

**CONTROLLER**

```js
    public function index(Request $request){ // TABLA PRINCIPAL
        if ($request->ajax()) {
            $profesor = profesorModel::latest()->get();  
            return datatables::of($profesor)
                    ->addIndexColumn()
                    ->addColumn('action', function($row){
                            // EL ROW DEBE INDICAR EL NOMBRE DE LA ID EN LA TABLA
                           $btn = '<div class="btn-group elevation-2">
                                        <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="tooltip"  data-id="'.$row->id_profesor.'" data-original-title="Ver" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-warning verProfesor"><i class="fas ion-ios-eye" style="width: 20px;"></i></a>
                                        <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="tooltip"  data-id="'.$row->id_profesor.'" data-original-title="Editar" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-info editarProfesor"><i class="fas ion-ios-create" style="width: 20px;"></i></a>
                                        <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="tooltip"  data-id="'.$row->id_profesor.'" data-original-title="Eliminar" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-danger eliminarProfesor"><i class="fas ion-md-trash" style="width: 20px;"></i></a>
                                    </div>';

                            return $btn;
                    })
                    ->addColumn('descargas', function($row){
                            // EL ROW DEBE INDICAR EL NOMBRE DE LA ID EN LA TABLA
                           $btn = '<div class="btn-group elevation-2">
                                        <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="tooltip"  data-id="'.$row->id_profesor.'" data-original-title="Descargar curriculum" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-info descargarCurriculum"><i class="fas ion-md-download" style="width: 20px;"></i> Curriculum</a>
                                        <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="tooltip"  data-id="'.$row->id_profesor.'" data-original-title="Descargar contrato" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-success descargarContrato"><i class="fas ion-md-download" style="width: 20px;"></i> Contrato</a>
                                    </div>';

                            return $btn;
                    })
                    ->rawColumns(['action','descargas'])
                    ->make(true);
        }
        return view('Profesor.profesor');
    }
```

Necesito que la columna 'descargas' se muestre según el rol o desaparezca según el rol

**IMAGEN CON LA COLUMNA**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer lo siguiente en la columna "descargas" que mencionas:

```
->addColumn('descargas', function($row){
                            // EL ROW DEBE INDICAR EL NOMBRE DE LA ID EN LA TABLA
                           $btn = '';
                           if($row->can('alumno.index')){
                              //Aquí si tiene ese permiso

                              //$btn .= 'Tengo el permiso'
                           }else{
                              //Aquí no lo tiene...

                           }


                            return $btn;
                    })
```

Dado que la variable `$row` que recibe tu función es un objeto de tu modelo que implementa los permisos, el método `can` debe de estar disponible en cada fila.

Comment: yo ya lo solucione pero no de esa manera, de todas formas igual intente tu manera pero me pide el metodo 'can' en mi modelo, dando este error:"Call to undefined method App\profesorModel::can()", la manera que hice, fue en el jquery, ir a la columna que quería ocultar y ponerle ahí el can, de esta manera "@can('profesor.destroy') {data: 'descargas', name: 'descargas', orderable: false, searchable: false} @endcan"

Comment: Lo siento, no especificaste que modelo es el que implementaba los permisos, pero si el modelo `profesorModel` no lo tiene pues si te marcará el error.